# Grouping By into a range in Java Streams

Tags: java, group-by, java-stream

I need to do something very simple but am not able to do it. I have an array of doubles called `brightnessArray` which I have extracted from an array of `HSB` (Hue, Brightness, Saturation) object like this:

```
double[] brightnessArray = Arrays.stream(hsbSourcePixelArray)
            .mapToDouble(b -> b.brightness).toArray();
```

Now, I need to group them in 256 bins. I am trying to do this by writing something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> brightnessHistogram = Arrays.stream(brightnessArray)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> b/256,  Collectors.counting()));
```

But this is not compiling at the `b/256` part where it says `Operator / cannot be applied to java.lang.Object, int`.

I am not sure how I do this grouping. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If brightness values are `double` then `Arrays.stream()` returns a specialized `DoubleStream`. You should look at the Javadoc for `DoubleStream` and especially its specialized `collect` method which will do what you want.  I don't have time to write a complete answer so this is just a hint to get you going in the right direction.  Once you solve it, if nobody has written an answer, write it yourself and I'll upvote it.

Comment: You can’t convert `double` to `Integer` without an explicit type conversion. That’s a fundamental rule, not related to lambda expressions or Streams at all. Since you also want to use `Stream.collect(Collector)`, you have to use `.mapToObj(b->(int)b)` in-between. Further, `counting()` collects to a `Long`, so the result would be `Map<Integer,Long>`…

Answer (score 0):

OK, you piqued my curiosity.  Here's one way to accomplish this.

```
    Stream<Double> ds = Arrays.stream(input).boxed();
    Map<Integer,Long> result = ds.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v->v.intValue()/256, Collectors.counting()));
```

This uses the cascading `groupingBy` that takes a second `Collector`.

There's probably a way to accomplish this with the `DoubleStream` but I discovered I don't know as much as I thought about the specialized streams yet.  Something interesting to study later.

Comment: v.intValue puts all in one bucket. On the other hand, v.doubleValue/256.0 says 'no instance of type variables exist so that Double conforms to Integer K has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Integer lower bounds: Double'. Currently in puts all the pixels to just one '0' bucket. But I want them to be in 256 buckets, hence would need v.doubleValue/256.0. How do we solve this?

Comment: Ah, It should be Map<Double, Long>. That fixed the static analysis warning

Comment: Interestingly, the number of elements in the map being created is 243 as compared to 256. Not sure why.

Comment: @Core_Dumped: It could be *any* number of elements. Your assumption that dividing by `256` will create 256 buckets, is entirely wrong. If you have *n* distinct numbers, dividing them by an ordinary number will produce *n* distinct numbers, only precision issues may reduce the set of numbers. But it will never be more than *n*…